# Replace text within string with array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

Rookie needing help!

```
    $some_text = "This red bag will contain green apples.";
    $extracted_array = array("red","bag","green","apples","what","why"); //obtained from database
```

I would like to replace each occurrence of the $extracted_array values in $some_text with a hyperlinked version of itself.

So "This red bag..." becomes

```
    This <a href="#">red</a> bag...
```

This is what I wrote:

```
    foreach($extracted_array AS $value) {
    $new_value = '<a href="#">'.$value.'</a>';
    $new_text = str_ireplace($value, $new_value, $some_text);
            }
    print_r($linked_content);
```

But this simply replaces each occurrence with the last value of the loop of $extracted_array (i.e. "why")

Please show me how I can do this right.

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.0, @Flosculus answer is the best one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$some_text = "This red bag will contain green apples.";
$extracted_array = array("red","bag","green","apples","what","why");

$expr = sprintf('/%s/i', implode('|', $extracted_array));

echo preg_replace_callback($expr, function($match){
    return sprintf('<a href="#">%s</a>', $match[0]);
}, $some_text);
```

Output:

```
This <a href="#">red</a> <a href="#">bag</a> will contain <a href="#">green</a> <a href="#">apples</a>.
```

Comment: This is definetely the best & proper way to do it!

Comment: This is a very good way to do it. It answers my question, but a little problem occurs when I insert the actual hyperlinks. "This red..." should actually become:"This <a href="/something/red/something">red</a>..."

Comment: `$match[0]` is the match of item in `$extracted_array`, the return value of the callback is what that pattern will be replaced with.  Im' sure you manipulate the return value further.  I'm just a `sprintf` freak, you can use `return '<a href="something/'.$match[0].'/something">'.$match[0].'</a>'`

Comment: Actually, after going further with what I need to do, your way works best. I guess I need to learn working with regex more

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better functions in PHP but I'll show you how to do it with your code:

```
$some_text = "This red bag will contain green apples.";
$extracted_array = array("red","bag","green","apples","what","why"); //obtained from database

foreach($extracted_array AS $value) {
    $new_value = '<a href="#">'.$value.'</a>';
    $some_text = str_ireplace($value, $new_value, $some_text);
}

print_r($some_text);
```

Your code takes everytime `$some_text` and saves it into `$new_text` but never changes `$some_text` therefor `$new_text` is the original of `$some_text` with changed last item of array.

Answer (score 0):

You could make two arrays, and send them in to str_ireplace. However, this might get cumbersome if the total number of replacements you are doing is quite large. The function will replace the string from $aFind with the item (with the same index) from $aReplace.

```
$aFind = array("red", "green");
$aReplace = array("<a href='/red.php'>red</a>", "<a href='/green.php'>green</a>");
$newString = str_ireplace($aFind, $aReplace, $some_text);
print($newString);
```

Comment: Thanks, this idea worked for me, but I still used str_replace. I'll post my answer above.